# Android call outsider class from service

Tags: android

I'm trying to call outsider class from service but encounter error like "null pointer exception". Here is simple code for that.

**here is outsider class.**

```
public class SyncTask {
    private Context context;

    public SyncTask(Context context, String agrs) {
        this.context = context;
    }       

    protected String ProcessSycn(String agrs) {     
        return agrs + " -  call successful.";
    }    
}
```

**here is service class.**

```
public class SyncService extends Service{   
    public SyncTask syncme;
    public String i;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);                
        i = syncme.ProcessSycn(3 + "");                                 
        this.stopSelf();
    }    


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }    
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of SyncTask class and ProcessSycn method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize the variable `syncme`. You need something like:

```
syncme = new SyncTask(this, "arguments");
```

Comment: I've declared the method but not initialize the variable. Let me test with your answer.

Comment: You need to add this code to `onStart()` before you use the variable `syncme`.

Comment: syncme = new SyncTask(this, "arguments");

Comment: public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
 super.onStart(intent, startId);
 syncme = new SyncTask(this, "3");
 i = syncme.ProcessSycn(3 + ""); 
} but failed.

Comment: What do you mean "failed"? You shouldn't have a `NullPointerException` now. Post more code and the errors you see in the Logcat and tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Also, if the method `ProcessSycn()` takes a long time then this will stall the main thread and your process will get killed with an ANR (Application Not Responding). If that method takes a long time then you need to do that in a background thread. When Android calls `onStart()` you need to return within a short period of time.

Comment: Yap, this outsider class will take long time to process.  This error may be cause of what you said?

Comment: If the call to `onStart()` takes too long to complete, then Android will just kill your process. But you should see that in the Logcat.